# Making a Popup ViewController out of a UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm working with a UITableViewController and when clicking a cell i would like to have a UICollectionViewController be popped up.

I've been successful in presenting the UICollectionViewController from a UITableViewController. However, I'm not able to figure out on how to present it like a pop-up only taking portion of the screen. It currently feels the entire view.

I searched on stackoverflow but couldn't find a working solution.

**UITableViewController**

```
class SearchViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {


let cellId = "cellId"
var filteredArray = [String]()
let books = Model().books

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    navigationItem.titleView = navSearchBar
    setupView()
}

// Views.
let navSearchBar = NavSearchBar()
func setupView() {
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    navSearchBar.delegate = self
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) { // Cancel button is touched.
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return books.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        book = books[indexPath.row]
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = book
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    let cellLabelContent = cell!.textLabel!.text // Gets cell name.
    let cellLabelIndex = bibleBooks.firstIndex(of: cellLabelContent!) // searches books array to get correct index of cell name.
    print("Book name:", cellLabelContent!+",", "index:", cellLabelIndex!)
    let notificName = Notification.Name(rawValue: searchedBookIndex)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: notificName, object: cellLabelIndex)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    **HERE is where i present the collectionView**
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    var topVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    while((topVC!.presentedViewController) != nil) {
        topVC = topVC!.presentedViewController
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ChapterNumbersCollectionView(collectionViewLayout: layout))
        topVC?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }      
}
```

**UICollectionViewController**

```
class ChapterNumbersCollectionView: UICollectionViewController {

let reuseIdentifier = "CellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupCollectionView()
    setupNavigationItem()
}

private func setupCollectionView() {
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

private func setupNavigationItem() {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setTitle("cancel", for: [])
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleDismiss), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 34, height: 34)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
}

@objc func handleDismiss() {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 200
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .red
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Your question is pretty broad,  but one approach would be to get rid of the UITableViewController and the UICollectionViewController and just place a UITableView and a UICollectionView into a view controller.  The initial height constraint for the collectionview would be 0 and when you select an item in the tableview, animate that height constraint to half of the screen height.

Comment: I recommend to add an UIView on your Tableview and add it with subclass and create your Collectionview in UIView

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik I believe i understand how to do what you suggested. I'll give it a try and see how it works out. Thanks

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik, i don't think it is possible to add a viewController as a subView when using a UIView

Comment: Apple documentation on custom transitions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/animation_and_haptics/view_controller_transitions There's also some good WWDC videos.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use [view controller containment.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) You'd instantiate ChapterNumbersCollectionView in `didSelectRow`, but instead of presenting, add it as a child view controller.

Then, having added its view as a subview, animate it in using [`animateWithDuration`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622515-animatewithduration)

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks.